# Viewing Google Satellite on my web map

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, openlayers, qgis2web

Please help me add "Google Satellite" to my web map by following the code below:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    
   Ext.QuickTips.init();

        var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                    -180,-90,180,90
                );
         
    var options = {
                  maxExtent: bounds,
                   // maxResolution:  0.222,
                    projection: "EPSG:4326",
                    allOverlays: true,
                    units: 'degrees',
                    //center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(23,77),
                    zoom: 5,
                    //controls:[new OpenLayers.Control.MouseDefaults()]                                         
                };
                
                
                var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
                        
                var OSM_base = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "OSM_base", "https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?",
                    {
                        LAYERS: 'OSM-WMS',                                             //  tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
                    },
                    { isBaseLayer: true,
                    displayInLayerSwitcher: true,}
                );

                                
                var tasmania_water_bodies = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "tasmania_water_bodies", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
                    {
                        LAYERS: 'topp:tasmania_water_bodies',
                        STYLES: '',
                        format: 'image/png',
                        //cql_filter: 'state_name == "BIHAR"',
                       tiled: true,
                        transparent: true
                      //  tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
                    },
                    {
                //  tileOptions: {maxGetUrlLength: 2048},
                    displayInLayerSwitcher: true,
                    isBaseLayer: false,
                    //singleTile: true,
                    transitionEffect: 'resize'
                    }
                );
                
                var tasmania_roads = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "tasmania_roads", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
                    {
                        LAYERS: 'topp:tasmania_roads',
                        STYLES: '',
                        format: 'image/png',
                        //cql_filter: 'state_name == "BIHAR"',
                       tiled: true,
                        transparent: true
                      //  tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
                    },
                    {
                //  tileOptions: {maxGetUrlLength: 2048},
                    displayInLayerSwitcher: true,
                    isBaseLayer: false,
                    //singleTile: true,
                    transitionEffect: 'resize'
                    }
                );
                
            map.addLayers([OSM_base,tasmania_water_bodies, tasmania_roads]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: You don't seem to be adding a Google layer to the map

Answer (score 1):

This is rather obsolete version V2 of OL. In OL 2 you can define Google satellite layer with:

```
var google_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Satellite",
    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels: 22}
)
```

Without Google API key you'll get text 'For developement purposes only' written all over the map. To get rid of it, you'll need Google API key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key